# Pydantic V2 @field_validator is not executed

Tags: python, pydantic-v2

I try to parse and validate a CSV file using the following Pydantic (V2) model.

```
from typing import Optional
from pydantic import BaseModel, field_validator
    
class PydanticProduct(BaseModel):
    fid: Optional[float]
    water: Optional[float]

    class ConfigDict:
        from_attributes = True

    @field_validator('fid', 'water',  mode='before')
    def check_empty_fields(cls, value) -> float:
        if value == '':
            return None
        try:
            float_value = float(value)
        except ValueError:
            raise ValueError("Unable to parse string as a number. Please provide a valid number.")
        return float_value
```

If the CSV file contents look like this

```
fid,water
1.0,81.3
1.25,26.3
3.0,31.5
```

the fields will get converted from strings to float correctly.

On the other hand if the CSV file contents have empty strings

```
fid,water
1.0,
,26.3
3.0,31.5
```

then I will get the following error

> Input should be a valid number, unable to parse string as a number [type=float_parsing, input_value='', input_type=str]

I tried to use the `@field_validator` with the `mode="before"` but the problem is that the validation is not executed.

In addition, I noticed that the validation is not executed even if there are no errors (aka. the case without empty strings)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From [the field validator documentation](https://docs.pydantic.dev/latest/concepts/validators/#field-validators)

> A few things to note on validators:
>
> - @field_validators are "class methods", so the first argument value they receive is the UserModel class, not an instance of UserModel. We recommend you use the @classmethod decorator on them below the @field_validator decorator to get proper type checking.

So you will need to add the missing `@classmethod` decorator.

```
from typing import Optional
from pydantic import BaseModel, field_validator
    
class PydanticProduct(BaseModel):
    fid: Optional[float]
    water: Optional[float]

    class ConfigDict:
        from_attributes = True

    @field_validator('fid', 'water',  mode='before')
    @classmethod
    def check_empty_fields(cls, value) -> float:
        if value == '':
            return None
        try:
            float_value = float(value)
        except ValueError:
            raise ValueError("Unable to parse string as a number. Please provide a valid number.")
        return float_value
```